# Problem finding multiplicative inverse c++

Tags: c++

I need to find the multiplicative inverse to some number e modulo ph. e is a prime number, ph is the result of the Euler function of some number. In the example e = 65537; ph = 3616319324. The pre-calculated correct value is 2373062985. On my own and with the help of the Internet, I wrote several functions to get this number. Functions using the extended Euler algorithm produce the same incorrect result, close to the maximum possible of variable type. A function based on Euler's theorem also gives an incorrect result, but different from the previous ones. What could be the problem here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

uint32_t xgcd1(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint64_t& x, uint64_t& y) {
    x = 1, y = 0;
    uint64_t x1 = 0, y1 = 1;
    uint32_t a1 = a, b1 = b;
    while (b1) {
        int q = a1 / b1;
        std::tie(x, x1) = std::make_tuple(x1, x - q * x1);
        std::tie(y, y1) = std::make_tuple(y1, y - q * y1);
        std::tie(a1, b1) = std::make_tuple(b1, a1 - q * b1);
    }
    return a1;
}

uint32_t xgcd2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint64_t& x, uint64_t& y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }

    uint64_t x1{}, y1{};
    uint32_t gcd = xgcd2(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return gcd;
}

std::vector<int64_t> euler(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    std::vector<int64_t> modInverse(x + 1, 0);
    modInverse[1] = 1;
    for (int64_t i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        modInverse[i] = (-(y / i) * modInverse[y % i]) % y + y;
    }
    return modInverse;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long ph = 3616319324;
    unsigned long e = 65537;
    uint64_t res1{}, y{};
    xgcd1(e, ph, res1, y);
    uint64_t res2{};
    xgcd2(e, ph, res2, y);
    uint64_t res3 = euler(e, ph)[e];
    std::cout << "e: " << e << '\n';
    std::cout << "ph: " << ph << '\n';
    std::cout << "right result: 2373062985\n";
    std::cout << "res1 xgcd iterative: " << res1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "res2 xgcd: " << res2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "res3 euler: " << res3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using unsigned types, but `y - q * y1` produces negative numbers every other iteration. You need to either use signed types or to adjust the algorithm. (The sign alternates every iteration, so you can compute `q * y1 - y` instead and remember the parity of the iteration count, or expand the loop to have two iterations written explicitly.) When you return the final result, you also need to return a signed result or wrap it modulo `b`. There may be other issues in the code; I did not check beyond that.

Comment: Yes, that's right, didn't notice signed numbers. But I still don't fully understand what should I do if I get a final negative x. I corrected the algorithm as you said, but I still get the wrong result - . Now it alternates between y - q * y1 and q * y1 - y every other iteration. Now i get 891072967, or -1243256339 if I use only signed numbers without modifications.

Comment: I figured out myself - if I get negative final x, I jut need to add ph to it. Now everything works, thank you!

Comment: Please either post the solution as an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the types from unsigned to signed. Also, if the result is negative, you need to add ph to it. And here's working code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int32_t xgcd1(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t& x, int64_t& y) {
    x = 1, y = 0;
    int64_t x1 = 0, y1 = 1;
    int64_t a1 = a, b1 = b;
    while (b1) {
        int q = a1 / b1;
        std::tie(x, x1) = std::make_tuple(x1, x - q * x1);
        std::tie(y, y1) = std::make_tuple(y1, y - q * y1);
        std::tie(a1, b1) = std::make_tuple(b1, a1 - q * b1);
    }
    return a1;
}

int64_t xgcd2(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t& x, int64_t& y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }

    int64_t x1{}, y1{};
    int64_t gcd = xgcd2(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return gcd;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long ph = 3616319324;
    unsigned long e = 65537;
    int64_t res1{}, y{};
    xgcd1(e, ph, res1, y);
    int64_t res2{};
    xgcd2(e, ph, res2, y);
    std::cout << "e: " << e << '\n';
    std::cout << "ph: " << ph << '\n';
    std::cout << "right result: 2373062985\n";
    if (res1 < 0)    // if negative add ph
        res1 += ph;
    if (res2 < 0)
        res2 += ph;
    std::cout << "res1 xgcd iterative: " << res1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "res2 xgcd: " << res2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```